# Error while sending email through smtp by zoho mail

Tags: c#-4.0, smtp, zoho

I am using zoho email for sending email. I have following configuration in my web.cfg.

```
   <add key="hostAddress" value="smtp.zoho.com" />
    <add key="portNo" value="587" />
    <add key="fromEmailAddress" value="info@something.com" />
    <add key="password" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

While sending email through above configuration and using SASL enables as true, I am getting below errors.

```
ERROR t:186 22/06/2016 08:36:28 EmailHelper            SendMail :: Error Message: Failure sending mail. Exception Detail System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 165.254.168.48:587
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Can you please help me in this as I have tried with all other ports(465) as well. I have windows hosting on goDaddy Servers. The code I have written in C# .net mvc-4. I am able to get emails when APIs are on localhost, when I deploy the same code on GoDaddy then It fails to send email.

Comment: You should share the code you wrote in C#

Comment: I am able to get emails when APIs are on localhost, when I deploy the same code on GoDaddy then It fails to send email.

Comment: @GirishGupta I know it is a very old question, have you found a solution or a workaround to this problem ?